# CHECKSUM_AGG and WHERE conditions in SQL

Tags: sql-server, conditional-statements, checksum

I am trying to find out when a table has been changed but only for rows that meet a specific condition. I have tried with this query:

```
SELECT CHECKSUM_AGG(BINARY_CHECKSUM(LastChanged)) FROM Products WHERE Category = 2 WITH (NOLOCK)
```

and I get a General SQL Server error. If I execute the query directly, the error is:

> Incorect syntax near '('

Is it possible to get the checksum for the rows that meet the condition only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is being caused by an incorrectly placed query hint, not by your use of a `CHECKSUM` expression.

Though it might help to read up on [whether you should really be using `NOLOCK` at all](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/), try putting `WITH (NOLOCK)` after your `FROM`:

```
SELECT CHECKSUM_AGG(BINARY_CHECKSUM(LastChanged)) 
FROM Products WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE Category = 2
```